# A column that's omitted during split-apply-combie in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions, split-apply-combine

I'm doing a split-apply-combine to find a total quantity for each member. The dataframe I need should have 14 columns: `MemberID, DSFS_0_1,  DSFS_1_2, DSFS_2_3, DSFS_3_4, DSFS_4_5, DSFS_5_6, DSFS_6_7, DSFS_7_8, DSFS_8_9, DSFS_9_10, DSFS_10_11, DSFS_11_12, DrugCount`. However, I'm not getting the 14th one (`DrugCount`), any idea why? The variable `joined` outputs all 14, but `joined_grouped_add`, the function in which I do aggregation, only returns 13.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model

# this function takes the drugcount dataframe as input and output a tuple of 3 data frames: DrugCount_Y1,DrugCount_Y2,DrugCount_Y3
def process_DrugCount(drugcount):
    dc = pd.read_csv("DrugCount.csv")
    sub_map = {'1' : 1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7+' : 7}
    dc['DrugCount'] = dc.DrugCount.map(sub_map)
    dc['DrugCount'] = dc.DrugCount.astype(int)
    dc_grouped = dc.groupby(dc.Year, as_index=False)
    DrugCount_Y1 = dc_grouped.get_group('Y1')
    DrugCount_Y2 = dc_grouped.get_group('Y2')
    DrugCount_Y3 = dc_grouped.get_group('Y3')
    DrugCount_Y1.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
    DrugCount_Y2.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
    DrugCount_Y3.drop('Year', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return (DrugCount_Y1,DrugCount_Y2,DrugCount_Y3)

# this function converts strings such as "1- 2 month" to "1_2"
def replaceMonth(string):
    replace_map = {'0- 1 month' : "0_1", "1- 2 months": "1_2", "2- 3 months": "2_3", "3- 4 months": '3_4', "4- 5 months": "4_5", "5- 6 months": "5_6", "6- 7 months": "6_7", \
                   "7- 8 months" : "7_8", "8- 9 months": "8_9", "9-10 months": "9_10", "10-11 months": "10_11", "11-12 months": "11_12"}
    a_new_string = string.map(replace_map)
    return a_new_string

# this function processes a yearly drug count data
def process_yearly_DrugCount(aframe):
    processed_frame = None
    aframe.drop("Year", axis = 1, inplace = True)
    reformed = aframe[['DSFS']].apply(replaceMonth)
    gd = pd.get_dummies(reformed)
    joined =  pd.concat([aframe, gd], axis = 1)
    joined.drop("DSFS", axis = 1, inplace = True)
    joined_grouped = joined.groupby("MemberID", as_index = False)
    joined_grouped_agg = joined_grouped.agg(np.sum)
    print joined_grouped_agg
    return processed_frame
def main():
    pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 
    daysinhospital = pd.read_csv('DaysInHospital_Y2.csv')
    drugcount = pd.read_csv('DrugCount.csv')
    process_DrugCount(drugcount)
    process_yearly_DrugCount(drugcount)
    replaceMonth(drugcount['DSFS'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And where are the lines that call the function(s)?

Comment: Too, too much is going on here to help. I advise breaking each part and adding print statements to view content to see where column is removed. Otherwise, set up a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I did print outputs along the way and broke it up. That's how I know that everything is fine, until I do the aggregation `joined_grouped_agg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, `DrugCount` pulled directly from csv is not reading in as a numeric field (int/float). Otherwise it would be retained in the `.agg(np.sum)` processing. Before aggregation check the dtype and see if it is an `object` type (i.e., string columns):

```
print joined['DrugCount'].dtype
```

In fact, in your `process_DrugCount()` function, you explicitly convert DrugCount column into integer with astype but do not do so in `process_yearly_DrugCount()` function. Run same line in latter function and DrugCount should be retained in aggregate sum processing:

```
aframe['DrugCount'] = aframe['DrugCount'].astype(int)
```

Or better yet, in `main()` to avoid doing conversion twice in latter functions:

```
drugcount['DrugCount'] = drugcount['DrugCount'].astype(int)
```

Also, do note, [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) allows explicit designation of columns types with its *dtype* argument:

```
drugcount = pd.read_csv('DrugCount.csv', dtype={'DrugCount': np.int64})
```